# Как из подключаемого файла PHP взять только переменную??? Чтобы остальной код не выполнялся!

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Как из подключаемого файла PHP взять только переменную??? Чтобы остальной код не выполнялся!!!!

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'action_ajax_form.php';

$codeInput = $_POST['code'];

$result;
if($codeInput == $code){
    $result = "НАЙС";
}else{
    $result = "ПЛОХО";
}

echo $code;
echo "<br>";
echo $result;
echo "<br>";
echo $codeInput;
?>
```

Comment: никак..............

Comment: правильно было бы сделать две страницы. на одной форма с аякс запросом к скрипту.